# (C++) Trouble writing hex to .dat file

Tags: c++, binary, hex, overwrite, ofstream

My program is pretty long and complex so I cannot explain it all, I will try to just explain my current situation, however.

I have a .dat file (729 of them but only 1 for this example) and I need to overwrite THE WHOLE FILE (even if my new data is smaller than the current data) with  a couple strings containing hex values.

Here is a snippet from my program:

```
ofstream xbox_final(xboxit->c_str(), ios::binary);

//other stuff

xbox_final.write("0a00000a00054c6576656c070006426c6f636b7300008000", 48);
xbox_final.write(new_bytes, new_bytes.length());
xbox_final.write(xboxbytes, xboxbytes.length());
xbox_final.close();
```

"xboxit->c_str()" in the ofstream is there because I'm inputting and outputting a BUNCH of files from a file list and this was necessary but gives me no errors, if that makes sense.

The strings "new_bytes" and "xboxbytes" contains hex values (000007000a0445 etc...)

For now my program has just been writing to a text document. I need it to write that hex data in that order to the .dat file.

I did some searching around and this fixes the const char problem:

```
//other stuff

string header("0a00000a00054c6576656c070006426c6f636b7300008000");

WriteStr2BinFh( header, xbox_final);
WriteStr2BinFh( new_bytes, xbox_final);
WriteStr2BinFh( xboxbytes, xbox_final);

//other stuff

void WriteStr2BinFh( const std::string& St, std::ostream &out ) 
{
    out.write( St.c_str(), St.size() );
}
```

Creating new .dat files somewhere else is also an acceptable option.

I JUST CAN'T WRITE THE HEX VALUES, THEY ALWAYS SHOW UP AS TEXT IN THE DAT FILE.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

A way to "easily" do that while keeping your current "model" would be to put `"\x"` in front of every of your hex value in your string. The compiler will then treat them as actual values, and not as a pair of characters.

What I mean is :

`std::cout << "4A4A" << std::endl;`

would output :

`4A4A`

whereas

`std::cout << "\x4A\x4A" << std::endl;`

would output:

`JJ`

since `0x4A` is the hexadecimal value for the ascii character `J`. Of course, the implications would be the same if you were writing this string to a file.

If you want to continue using a string to store it, you'll need to change the constructor since your string will contain the value `0`.

`string header("your_hex_chain", number_of_bytes_in_your_chain); // \x00 is one byte, for example`

It would, however, be much easier to use a `struct` to store the values of your header, and write if directly to the .dat file. But I don't know much more about what you're trying to do, so...

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! By doing the \x thing, how would this effect hex values with no character assigned to them? example: 00-> 09 are "null" if you will and will show up as spaces. Would the hex data write properly to the file? Also, I have never used const before because I am just a beginner. I got the code with the const from online. I will need to store everything in SOMETHING because it is a HUGE amount of hex stored. Nothing I could /x every time.

Comment: You just edited the post ---> Yeah I don't know what a struct is either. I could look it up, but I figured there was a quick and easy way to write the data back in just like I read it.

Comment: 00->09 are non-printable characters - you could not humanly read them, but they would appear as values in the file. You could just try it out with a very small code : try and write "\x00\x01\xothervalues" to a file and open it with an hexadecimal editor to get a good idea. As for your second question, it all depends how you get your values in the first place !

Comment: Yes the \x thing works great! I am able to write the header just fine. I put my own hex values into each string based on data read from a text file. I would read in 0007070701010101..... etc from a txt, then convert it to what I need it to be and put it in a string. Also, how could I solve my problem where I need it to overwrite the whole file? I need to erase everything currently in the dat file and write my new data.

Comment: If you read your hex values as _text_, you'll need to convert each pair of characters to an integer value. If you read your hex values as _values_, then you have no such processing to do and can simply write it to your file immediately. Overwriting your own file is easy : take a look at the constructors of `ofstream`, one option allows you to completely empty the file you are opening.

Comment: I found ios::trunc. so that solves that problem.  :) How would I go about converting each pair to an integer value? That seems like it would take a while.

Comment: I added "\x" to the new_bytes string every 2 hex characters and it still writes to the file as text.....

Comment: That'll need a bit of work. One solution could be to use a loop of calls to strtol, or something like that. I don't really have enough time to expand on that problem, but that's a way you could consider.